# undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) | ruby / codewars question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
    def comp(array1, array2)
  d = array2 - array1.map{|x| x.pow(2)}
  d == [] ? true : false
end
```

Error exit code:

main.rb:4:in `comp': undefined method` -' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from main.rb:35:in `block in <main>' from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:55:in` block in describe'
from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:46:in `measure' from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:51:in` describe'
from main.rb:7:in `'

This is my first post here, so sorry if I made any mistake :/

@Edit:
Added 'if'

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  if array1 == nil or array2 == nil
    return false
  else
    d = array2 - array1.map{|x| x.pow(2)}
    d == [] ? true : false
  end
end
```

Comment: you're not passing `array2` to that method

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry but could You explain it a little more please? Thank You in advance! :)

Comment: Show where you call that method.

Comment: More specifically `array2` is `nil`. We would still need to see where it's called and also surrounding code.

Comment: So I guess, I can call the method like this, can't I? `comp([2,4,6], [4,16,36])`
@SiimLiiser there is no surrounding code, it's just a codewars training, and I passed all tests but there is an exit code error. I'm new to ruby and in programming at all. It's my frist time I meet something like this, I tried it on irb in cmd and it did work, so I ddecied to ask here. :/

Comment: I can put a screen of it [lmgbb](https://ibb.co/tLkDTt8)

Comment: Trying your code as is works for me if you call it as `comp([2,4,6], [4,16,36])`. Your issue is somewhere else.

https://tio.run/##LYzBCoQgFEX3fsVdJrwJdMJFEPMh4sIZbTWVWFJR8@0GOat7DhxuTO89Z@d7fKYhVDZGuwvCvZIzwKH7Gx4FRD3YcJzbia0O01pJ/itdB23wwhKTR4vefmfP/OgYC2mZy7@W1JAyBN2QUPRUhud8AQ

Comment: Okay, so I got something like this 
 `if array1 == nil or array2 == nil return false`
 and now there is another problem, because I've not passed one of the tests, now I'll try to figure it out! Thank You guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I read the description of the Kata and thought about just posting it in the comments but I figured why not help a bit.

In the description it states:

> a or b might be nil or null or None or nothing (except in C++, Elixir, Haskell, PureScript, Pascal, R, Rust, Shell).
>
> If a or b are nil (or null or None), the problem doesn't make sense so return false.

So your issue right now is that `b` is `nil` and thus the error because `nil:NilClass` does not have a `-` method.

To guard from this and to complete the Kata we can redesign your method as follows:

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  return false unless array1 && array2
  d = array2 - array1.map{|x| x.pow(2)}
  d == [] ? true : false
end
```

This clause `return false unless array1 && array2` means that both `array1` and `array2` must be truthy. In ruby everything is truthy except `nil` and `false`.
<sub>Normally I would write this as `return unless array1 && array2` but the Kata explicitly said return `false`</sub>

That being said we can clean up your code a bit more. Let's take a look at this part first `d == [] ? true : false`. `d == []` will return a Boolean (`true`/`false`) so logically putting this into words it reads "If d equals empty Array equals true then true OR If d equals empty Array equals false return false".

As you can see based on reading that we can shorten this to "return d equals empty Array" or (`d == []`). Now that is a bit better however a bit functional. Ruby is an extremely object oriented programming language, literally everything is an Object, and in object oriented programming objects have methods. IF we take a look at the `Array` object we can see that it has an `empty?` method so we can simply call `d.empty?`

So now our code looks like this:

```
def comp(array1, array2)
  return false unless array1 && array2
  d = array2 - array1.map{|x| x.pow(2)}
  d.empty?
end
```

There is some additional refactoring that could be done but this should get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: I really appreciate that! Thank You! <3 I understood everything!

Comment: There is still 1 problem, can it be a problem with duplicates of elements in arrays?

Comment: I added this `if array1.uniq && array2.uniq` then code `else return false`. And there is still a problem... :/

Comment: @Patryk yes but then you can't use Array subtraction. `array1.sort.map {|e| e**2} == array2.sort` will work